# Heavy content-based iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

My application is content-based. So, it contains a lot of graphics, like photos and pictures.

Until now it was only for iPad, but we want to support iPhone too. App size is about 200 MB now, but with iPhone 5, 6, 6 Plus resources it will grow significantly.

The second problem is that i need to choose the right resource and i can't put it into assets, because almost all of them are jpegs. So, if I keep all the resources in bundle, I need to give them names like `image_name@2x~ipad`, `image_name@2x~iphone-568h`, `image_name@2x~iphone-667h`, `image_name@2x~iphone-736h` and so on. After that I need to write a `UIImage` category that will choose the right resource.

I've thought about downloading specific resources from server on the first application launch. But, as I read, it's a bad UX.

Does someone know a better way to support many devices?

Comment: Use stretchable images wherever it's possible.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, maybe the question is a bit stupid, but what are stretchable images? Vector graphics? How can i do that with photos?

Comment: You can use '- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` for buttons, bars, backgrounds, etc. Using vector graphics is good choise, but I not sure is `UIImage` supports vector formats. I think you will need manually render them at first use.

Comment: @Cy-4AH, thanks, i've got the thing... but that's nothing to do with photos. And they are the general part of the application...
Scaling photos leads to bad quality

Comment: @АнтонТютин well...leads to bad quality if you do zoom in, but not if you zoom out; if you have the big images and scale them to a minor size youre not going to have that issue

Comment: @oPi, nope, you are not right.

I've been working on that issue. Scaling to a minor size can lead to a very bad results.

You'd need additional actions, like antialiasing to overcome this problem